# 1-form that compute the area of parallelogram

Tags: differential-geometry

Find a form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that compute the area of parallelogram generate by any pair of vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ which are in the plane $\pi=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4| \vec{x}=\vec{p}+s\vec{u}+t\vec{v}, s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Let $\omega$ and $\eta$ $1$-forms, so the area of parallelogram generate by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is

$\omega\wedge\eta(\vec{a},\vec{b})=\begin{vmatrix} \omega(\vec{a}) & \omega(\vec{b})\\ \eta(\vec{a}) & \eta(\vec{b}) \end{vmatrix}$

I don't know how to continue.